# Error while compiling C multiple files

Tags: c++, class, constructor, cmake

I'm using

1. main.cpp
2. FileSystem Class - holds 2 directories (root and current)
3. Directory Class - inherits from BaseFile
4. File Class - inherits from BaseFile

I'm trying to create a new directory and set it to be root.
My constructors are:

```
BaseFile::BaseFile() {
name = "default";
}
Directory::Directory() {
    parent = nullptr;
    cout << "Directory: Default Constructor" << endl;
}
```

When trying to use `FileSystem::FileSystem() {
    root = new Directory();
}`

I get a compilation error saying:

```
    /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /Users/adammorad/ver1/cmake-build-debug --target ver1 -- -j 2
Scanning dependencies of target ver1
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ver1.dir/FileSystem.cpp.o
[ 66%] Linking CXX executable ver1
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Directory::Directory()", referenced from:
      FileSystem::FileSystem() in FileSystem.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [ver1] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ver1.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ver1.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [ver1] Error 2
```

Comment: You should post & double check the contents of your cmake targets (`add_executable` and friends, as well as `target_link_libraries` and friends).

Comment: Indeed, the problem was that somehow the files for the Directory class werent in the cmake target - I just changed it and everything compiles fine.